# How to test Redis Time out exception for @Cacheable method with Junit+ Spring integration test

Tags: spring, redis, junit4, spring-test, spring-data-redis

I have a repository class in which have one repository method which call the database. I have made this method cacheable by using Spring annotation @Cacheable.

I do use Redis cache.  Now, I have also implemented Spring provided CacheErrorHandler which handles the Redis runtime exceptions. However, I am not able to Unit test this implemented GlobalCacheErrorHandler class because I am not able to mock this @Cacheable method in such a way that it throws the RedisTimeOut exception.

Please find below the required code snippet which helps to understand the issue.

```
@Repository
Class EmployeeRepository {

@Cacheable(cacheNames = EMPLOYEE_CACHE, cacheManager = REDIS_CACHE_MANAGER, key = “’EId_' + #p0", unless = "#result.size()==0")
List<Employee> findByEmplyeeId(Long employeeid);

}
```

```
public class GlobalCacheErrorHandler implements CacheErrorHandler {

    public GlobalCacheErrorHandler() {
        log.info("GlobalCacheErrorHandler initialized");
    }
    @Override
    public void handleCacheGetError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
        
    log.error(“Could not get the value from cache”);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCachePutError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key, Object value) {
        log.error(“Could not put the value for the key”);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCacheEvictError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
    log.error(“Could not evict value for the key");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCacheClearError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache) {
    log.error(“Could not clear the cache");
   }

}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@CustomLog
public class ApplicationCacheConfiguration extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

@Bean
@Override
public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
    return new GlobalCacheErrorHandler();
}

}
```

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot, have you tried `@MockBean`?

Comment: @SamBrannen yes, have tried that out, too. In this case, cache is being called via spring interceptor. And there is no way I found how can I mock this functionality.  Especially when I want to create the scenario when Redis cache gives runtime exception using Junit.